# How to delete a stored site in MTPuTTY

Tags: windows, putty

Is it possible to delete a server with MTPuTTY? With regular PuTTY this is possible, but I have not been able to find a button or shortcut to do this with MTPuTTY. I am using Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems not to be implemented.

You probably have to delete the stored session in PuTTY and then use the *Reload PuTTY sessions* command in MTPuTTY.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, edit `[Drive]:\Users\[You]\AppData\Roaming\TTYPlus\mtputty.xml`

Remove the items from the `<Recents>` section.

Make sure you get the indexes in the tag names right once you remove stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Actually none of the above works 100%. Check that while configuring Mtputty what configuration file you specified. Then from there open the XML file e.g. for me it was D:\SOFTWARES\mtputty.xml and remove the items from the  section.

Answer (score 0):

From directory where the mtputty.exe is starting up. I have removed file mtputty.sessions.xml and file mtputty.dock.xml

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).